# how can i add another textbox in link module in drupal 7

Tags: 7, entities

I have an article content type with author name. I can add a link field to the article with the use of the link module. I also show the author name of the article without a link. How is it possible to do this through the link module?

Comment: Is the author name you're talking about an additional field you have in your content type (not the default author information Drupal collects by default)?  If so, did you just add that as a text field to begin with and now you're wondering how to do it as a link?  I just want to make sure I'm understanding your issue...

Comment: yes author name is additional filed in my content type. now this author name i want to show in link but by default link module add "title" and "url".

Comment: Do you want the author names to link to outside content or internal nodes/user profiles?

Comment: now i don't want to link author name to outside content. Now i just show this article belong to this author. for example   "Sufi Contribution to Education"
—Abul Wafa El-Taftazani

Comment: Where "Sufi Contribution to Education" is title of article and "—Abul Wafa El-Taftazani " is author. when user click on title then he go to article link page.

Comment: OK, I think I understand.  It sounds like you're trying to display two separate fields together.  I don't know that you can combine a second field into the link.  It sounds like this may be where you need to think about theming the output of this content type.  Here's a tutorial if you want to go that route: http://lin-clark.com/blog/intro-drupal-7-theming-fields-and-nodes-templates

Comment: Yes i am trying to display two separate fields title and author where title is link and author is only showing per-pus. now you can also suggest any other module .....

Comment: Well, they're separate fields, but if you don't like the way Drupal displays them by default, I'd just theme the output as above.  I'm not sure of a module that combines fields together, but maybe somebody else does.  My best advice is the theming.  Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: thanks Boriana given your valuable time now i am trying to complete this work with theming...